# AWS IAM Trust Policy for Assumed Role

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I have a cross-account VPC peering authorizer role that I use to automatically accept peering connections via CloudFormation. The problem is I want to run the VPC peering template as an assumed role. The role ARN has a session name at the end. I cannot add a principal to my authorizer role trusted entities because the role with session name only "exists at runtime". The CloudFormation fails to assume the role because arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/Admin/session-name is not a principal in my trust policy, only arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/Admin. I can't use wildcard and the Admin/session-name isn't a permanent role in the account.

Is this possible? How can I authorize an assumed role with session name in a trust policy?

Edit: Solved. My trust policy principal should be arn:aws:sts::123456788:assumed-role/Admin/session-name rather than arn:aws:iam

Answer (score 4):

Solved. My trust policy principal should be arn:aws:sts::123456788:assumed-role/Admin/session-name rather than arn:aws:iam...