# Cross Account Policies for Service Role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to have CodeBuild in account A pushing an image to a ECR of account B, but I am getting permissions issue.

I have the following policy in account B:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
            "ecr:*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*"
    }]}
```

And a role ecrManager in account B with such policy attached, and following trusted relationship:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::accountA:root"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Condition": {}
    }]}
```

I have then in account A the role used by CodeBuild with following policy:

```
       {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::accountB:role/ecrManager"
    },
```

But when I run code Build, I get the following error in CloudTrail:

```
    "errorMessage": "User: arn:aws:sts::accountA:assumed-role/CodeBuild-CodeBuildServiceRole-1RHFVAD5WW6J4/AWSCodeBuild-b7487523-7e3a-4219-bee7-08e6e40a3f21 is not authorized to perform: ecr:InitiateLayerUpload on resource: arn:aws:ecr:ca-central-1:accountB:repository/demo because no resource-based policy allows the ecr:InitiateLayerUpload action"
```

What did I do wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49925395/13126651 did you checked this?

Answer (score 0):

The resource based policy need to be updated

from

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::accountA:root"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Condition": {}
    }]}
```

to

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::[accountAID]:role/CodeBuild-CodeBuildServiceRole"
    }
}
```

here is a blog on how to create cross account access role
https://dev.to/kasukur/how-to-delegate-access-across-aws-accounts-using-iam-roles-43ej

Could you please try this and let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for this. It however does not solve the problem:
I put "arn:aws:iam::510477020878:role/CodeBuild-CodeBuildServiceRole-1RHFVAD5WW6J4" in my trusted relationship, but I still get the error.
Thanks for the link, this is the one I followed, but it explained for a User to do cross account operation, not for a Service so I believe I made mistake link to this.

Comment: I think I know what the issue is "CodeBuild supports cross-account resource sharing using AWS RAM" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html

I am happy to delete my answer if required as it doesn't answer your question.

Comment: I found the issue, I was not assuming the role in the CodeBuild script. This tutorial actually explained how to do it:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/codebuild-temporary-credentials-docker/

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that I was not assuming the role in the code build script.
This AWS tutorial explain nicely how it should have been done:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/codebuild-temporary-credentials-docker/